# firebase callable function (hello-wolrd-level) deadline-exceeded

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

A hello world level callable function get deadline exceeded after 70 seconds, even though the responsed correctly.

the callable funciton:

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return { test: "hello world" };
});
```

client side:

```
const onClick = () => {
  helloWorld()
    .then(res => {
      console.log({ res });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPm49.png)

successfully get response from callable function on the browser => { test: "hello world" }

Error: deadline-exceeded

error is throwed by:

```
 * @param millis Number of milliseconds to wait before rejecting.
 */
function failAfter(millis) {
    return new Promise(function (_, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            reject(new HttpsErrorImpl('deadline-exceeded', 'deadline-exceeded'));
        }, millis);
    });
}

    /**
     * Calls a callable function asynchronously and returns the result.
     * @param name The name of the callable trigger.
     * @param data The data to pass as params to the function.s
     */
    Service.prototype.call = function (name, data, options) {
        return tslib.__awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
            var url, body, headers, context, timeout, response, error, responseData, decodedData;
            return tslib.__generator(this, function (_a) {
                switch (_a.label) {
                    case 0:
                        url = this._url(name);
                        // Encode any special types, such as dates, in the input data.
                        data = this.serializer.encode(data);
                        body = { data: data };
                        headers = new Headers();
                        return [4 /*yield*/, this.contextProvider.getContext()];
                    case 1:
                        context = _a.sent();
                        if (context.authToken) {
                            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + context.authToken);
                        }
                        if (context.instanceIdToken) {
                            headers.append('Firebase-Instance-ID-Token', context.instanceIdToken);
                        }
                        timeout = options.timeout || 70000;
                        return [4 /*yield*/, Promise.race([
                                this.postJSON(url, body, headers),
                                failAfter(timeout),
                                this.cancelAllRequests
                            ])];
                    case 2:
                        response = _a.sent();
                        // If service was deleted, interrupted response throws an error.
                        if (!response) {
                            throw new HttpsErrorImpl('cancelled', 'Firebase Functions instance was deleted.');
                        }
                        error = _errorForResponse(response.status, response.json, this.serializer);
                        if (error) {
                            throw error;
                        }
                        if (!response.json) {
                            throw new HttpsErrorImpl('internal', 'Response is not valid JSON object.');
                        }
                        responseData = response.json.data;
                        // TODO(klimt): For right now, allow "result" instead of "data", for
                        // backwards compatibility.
                        if (typeof responseData === 'undefined') {
                            responseData = response.json.result;
                        }
                        if (typeof responseData === 'undefined') {
                            // Consider the response malformed.
                            throw new HttpsErrorImpl('internal', 'Response is missing data field.');
                        }
                        decodedData = this.serializer.decode(responseData);
                        return [2 /*return*/, { data: decodedData }];
                }
            });
        });
    };
    return Service;
}());
```

Comment: I'm behind a proxy , I can login to google cloud in terminal , deploy function properly, but would that be the cause? I get the response already from the callable function , It's like the promise on client side is not resolved.

Comment: How do you define `helloWorld()` in your client?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Sorry for the delayed response. this.is the complete client code 
   `const  helloWorld = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("helloWorld");
const onClick = () => {
  helloWorld()
    .then(res => {
      console.log({ res });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};      `                I called the cloud function all right, but when openning the chrome dev tool , It will remind me deadline exceeded .